# Click on childNode automatically

Tags: javascript, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I am using the following script, but it does not work the part where I click. I need to click on a childNodes automatically.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var formatDropDown = document.getElementById('rvProcess_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Menu');
        var formats = formatDropDown.childNodes;

        if (formatDropDown != null) {
            formatDropDown.removeChild(formats[3]);
            formatDropDown.removeChild(formats[1]);
        }

        **var item = formatDropDown.getElementsByTagName('LI')[2];
        item.click();**

    }
</script>
```

thanks

Comment: Do you get any errors? And are you sure you still have 3 LIs in the list at that point? Because that should work, see http://jsfiddle.net/Ykgyv/

Comment: @bfavaretto click does not work, because it does not export the report

Comment: See my updated comment, it should be working. Check your console for errors.

Comment: @bfavaretto I get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of undefined"

Comment: Then your code is not finding 'rvProcess_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Menu'  getElementById is returning undefined.

Comment: Given that error, I believe your list has less than 3 items at that point; you're trying to target the third one (index 2) and it can't be found.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show as the HTML code of yours  list?
Having this html code everything works well

```
<ul id="rvProcess_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Menu"><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li></ul>
```

I advise you to write code in a line when you want to work with children nodes. White spaces and linebreaks are treating as children of text type.
I implemented a jQuery for try if the last li clicked, I did the following:

```
window.onload = function () {
            $("li").click(function(e){
                alert("clicked");
            });
            var formatDropDown = document.getElementById('rvProcess_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Menu');
            var formats = formatDropDown.childNodes;
            if (formatDropDown != null) {
                formatDropDown.removeChild(formats[3]);
                formatDropDown.removeChild(formats[1]);
            }

            var item = formatDropDown.getElementsByTagName('LI')[2];
            item.click();
        }
```

And it works perfect.

Comment: I do not pollute the answers, I want to see the html code, because I have everything works fine, but I want to help people

Comment: You posted a *comment* as an *answer*. Perhaps 'pollute' was too strong a term, but your comment is, definitely, not an answer. When you get more rep you can comment below the question, but until then please don't leave comments as answers.

Comment: Thank you very much, for enlightenment, Captain Obvious